# VMDK file size much larger than allocated

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have a bunch of disks attached to a virtual machine that hosts backups for other servers around our client networks. I was looking at datastore usage recently and found that all of the disks are significantly larger in the datastore than the disk size reported in ESXi and in the guest operating system.

For instance, the OS disk for the VM was created as 80GB (thick eager zeroed) but the file size in the datastore is reported as a little over 120GB. One of the backup target disks (also thick eager zeroed) is 3.5TB in size but the VMDK file occupies ~5.3TB!

For all of the disks on the backup server that are thick provisioned the same is true. All of the VMDK files are ~1.5x the size shown in VSphere and in the guest. All told I've lost over 7TB worth of space on this one VM, and other eager zeroed disks exhibit similar overheads.

There are no snapshots - none at present certainly - and nothing else I can see that would inflate the disk usage.  The datastore is configured as NFS.

Two questions:

1. Why the discrepancy?
2. What can I do to reclaim this space?

If necessary I'll rebuild the drives - I have space enough for it if I'm careful.  In the long term I will be needing that extra space.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file

Comment: @jordanm I've heard of sparse files, sure.  If you think this explains 7TB worth of wasted space I'd be interested in how that would work.